# How to sync Wordpress plugins between instances deployed with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does anybody know how can I sync the plugins of a Wordpress deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk between all deployed instances?

I can easily deploy a Wordpress to EBeanstalk (even AWS give us a template for this) but if I install a plugin, it is installed in only one instance. There's no guarantee that any other user (or even myself) will access that instance again with the autoscaling happening. I already tested it and I could not access it in another instances.

I know the uploads folder will have the same problem, but there are already plugins to sync it with S3.

Thank you!

Comment: are plugins part of the application source?

Answer (score 1):

Research "stateless wordpress".  I found a good starting point on Mike Otreva's site.  In short, the solution involves building an example AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment and then using GIT to push your WP build.  You'll need to set-up up a local Xamp environment in order to be able to GIT push your build.  Once you do it this way, you'll never update plugins from the dashboard, instead you'll update your local build and then push the updates to your environment.  You might even want to install a plugin that stops all automatic updates.  I hope that helps some.